# Creating a winforms app that allows drag and dropping of custom 'widgets'

Tags: winforms

I want to create a winforms application, this application will be similiar to the vs.net winforms designer (in certain aspects).

Basically it is going to be a blank page, where the user can drag and drop a bunch of 'widget's onto the screen.  The widgets are basically custom images that I will create, that the user can resize, and it has some text on it by default which the user can double click on it to change the text.

Is this doable in winforms?  If yes, what are the key aspects that I have to learn?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to do in WinForms. Check out [basic drag and drop](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms.aspx). It's targeted toward 2.0. You'll use the DoDragDrop() method and capture data in drag and drop events. It requires some verbosity, but it gets the job done.

If you're keen on using WPF, take a look at [MSDN's topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).